# Why does Django Reverse URL return app_name?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-urls

I am configuring my URLs as follows:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('personal', views.EventPersonalViewSet)
router.register('public', views.EventPublicViewSet)

app_name = 'event'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

I would expect to reverse the URLs like this:

```
EVENT_PERSONAL_URL = reverse('event:personal-list')
EVENT_PUBLIC_URL = reverse('event:public-list')
```

However, I am only able to reverse one URL like this:

```
reverse('event:event-list')
```

Running manage.py show_urls returns the following configuration:

> /api/event/personal/  event.views.EventPersonalViewSet    event:event-list
>
> /api/event/personal./    event.views.EventPersonalViewSet    event:event-list
>
> /api/event/public/    event.views.EventPublicViewSet  event:event-list
>
> /api/event/public./  event.views.EventPublicViewSet  event:event-list

Why would reverse() reference app_name rather than the specified path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is because you have not mentioned basename in router.register.

you should try by adding basename in router.register like this

```
router.register(prefix='personal', views.EventPersonalViewSet, basename='personal')
```

now, you will be able to use the reverse url by using
reverse('event:personal-list')